# Is it possible to build an enterprise application with C/C++?

Tags: c++, c

So, I heard that facebook used C for their underlying business logic, with PHP as the front end. Now I'm learning C++, and my assignment in 2 weeks is to develop a crossword puzzle game for people to play. I finish the program to produce a crossword puzzle with possibility of highest combination between words. The input is from file uploaded by the user or let them enter. Now I'm doing the frontend, and I'm pretty amazed that I can embed C++ code into my web pages, things which I thought never exists, is totally possible with embedded server like Klone: http://www.koanlogic.com/klone/ and web toolkit for C++ like: http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt.

I really like C++ because it's a pretty general purpose language. If I can develop business website using C/C++, I can practice C/C++ a lot, and I hope I can perform system call on linux to practice it. After graduating, based on knowledge my university provided, I will be more specialised in web development. The thing is, I still want to program in C/C++, so later I can switch to fields such as game programming or embedded system programming.

So, do you have any opinions, advises and experience on this issue?

Comment: See [the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for why this is not an appropriate question.

Comment: this question really deserves a lot better subject line. As it stands you could just be trolling, with an enormously high likelihood. I kind of like what you bring forward (Klone, e.g.), but it is going to be hard to `in abstracto` respond to this

Comment: On of the most given advice on this site is:"Use the right tool for the job.". While C++ is a powerful language, it is not well suited for web development. If you're not a top notch C++ coder, I wouldn't even recommend it for the back end (I'm developing a front end for a C++ server, and it leaks memory like hell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we are sharing ideas:

Let's not forget about **[Google's Native Client project](http://www.chromium.org/nativeclient)** which -frankly- rocks. It will allow you to run *any* about any native code in the browser, by compiling it into verifiable object format (much like say verifyable managed code that is the basis for Silverlight, but not tied to any VM).

### Video link

I dug up [the video link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L8m9U7p_Ntk&feature=related) I found most informative when I first found out about NaCl

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful. I will study this carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question - **yes**.

But should you? There are many tools that are best for specific tasks. Like PHP for web development. You won't write an OS with PHP, so why write web pages with C++?

Comment: Because I want to practice my C/C++ skill with the web development, and later potentially switch field. The problem is there's really a lot of programming languages for web development out there. If I specialise into one, after a long time I may not program other languages as good. Therefore, I want to pick a general purpose languages, so I can be versatile in many fields (later I can learn more about C/C++ to switch to game or embedded system programming for example)

Comment: @Amumu - if it's for your own practice - by all means, go for it. If it's a commercial application then you need to think of the time and effort you're going to spend writing in C++ things that are built in in PHP.

Comment: Imagine like I have my own web server, which runs on Linux. Isn't that cool If I can perform system calls from my C/C++ modules to my own server? I feel like I have more control over my server.

Comment: @Amumu - cool? don't know. Dangerous? You bet.

Comment: If you're any good at your job, you can learn more than one language and be fluent in several of them at once. That's the way to go, because "nobody" will hire you to write web applications in C++.

Comment: @littleadv I don't know about the productivity gain when using PHP. I did a bit of PHP programming (an online store website). I don't know if there's any different by coding with PHP with other frameworks. When I was doing php assignment, I still have to write code line by line and now I am learning C++, I feel the basic syntax is mostly identical. On the other hand, if C++ does not have application on the web development field, so why there are people who make the web server such as Klone?

Comment: @Amumu: `I don't know about the productivity gain when using PHP` - I suggest you learn it. Or C#, or Coffee-script. Or python. You'll _know_. `I feel the basic syntax is mostly identical` - The syntax is not the issue. The abstraction and safety are the differences