# What is the C++ equivalence for a server side that uses Servlets & JSP?

Tags: java, c++, jsp, servlets, client-server

When I'm using JAVA in the server side , I use JSP's and Servlets .

What is the C++ equivalence for a server side (that is JSP's and Servlets when using JAVA) ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I would say ASP.net for C++, this is the only thing I can think of

Comment: .NET supports C# , does it also supports C++ ?

Comment: It does. But it is no longer recommended by the officials (Microsoft).

Answer (score -2):

Already discussed

[Is it possible to build an enterprise application with C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781976/is-it-possible-to-build-an-enterprise-application-with-c-c)

Enterprise application is a failure for C++ i would say. Nevertheless, answering your question. There are frameworks like **Visual C++**

Comment: Visual C++ is basically a development kit (compiler, IDE), it is certainly not a framework.